# Does CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting memoize?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

If I have some code that calls CloudConfigurationManager.GetSettings for every request, will my performance suffer due to repeated disk access every time or are the results memoized so only the first request for a given setting will go to disk and the rest of them will use memoized results?

I can do this for every one of my configuration settings, but I would rather not (too much code overhead):

```
private String Foo { get { return _foo ?? (CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(FooSettingName)); } }
private String _foo = null;
private const String FooSettingName = @"MyNamespace.Foo";
```

I could also build a general purpose memoizing dictionary, but I would rather not if it is unnecessary.